# Is it possible to visualize (on a google map) the path a Tor client takes?

Tags: network-configuration

I want to promote the usage of Tor, but I have some visual learners who want to see Tor's connections and the paths that are taken.

Is there any visual diagnostic or learning tool that will help empower Tor users to see the connection "bounce around the world" so they feel safe and private?

Answer (score 1):

"bounce around the world" is not what makes Tor safe and private. It would be giving users a false sense of security. Vidalia used to do this and I'm still fighting against the false ideas it implanted in users heads.

Yes, geographic distribution is important but:

1. IP addresses have *no correlation to geographic location*.
2. You cannot know the path that the traffic takes between relays.
3. Tor Browser already shows the claimed location of the relays.
4. Geo*political* distance is more important that geo*graphic* distance.